# Using Python FTP_lib to delete file is generating an FTP550 error

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm trying to use a script that would automate deletion of images from a website using FTP and Python.  My script is as follows:

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('#server','#user','#pw')
session.delete("#path_to_file_on_webserver")
```

This is generating the following error:
error_perm: 550 Could not delete "#file_to_path_on_webserver": No such file or directory.

The path to the file is definitely correct and copying that to the browser takes me to the image.  I should add that I'm using what I believe to be the full path - "http://websitename.com/pathstoimage/image.jpg"

I spoke to my webhost who changed permissions to the image folder to 777 and to the files as 777 but I'm still getting that error.  What's stranger is that I can modify the script to upload images to the server and that works okay, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what's gone wrong.  Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: run session.dir() before just to confirm the path

Comment: I'm not sure what that's supposed to do... I've added it to my code just after the 2nd line and printed the results out.  It's just printing out a table of what looks to be previous FTP connections but nowhere in this table can I find the path.

Comment: HTTP URL has nothing to do with FTP. Can you delete that file using any (GUI) FTP client? Use the path that you see in the FTP client.

Comment: Yeah I've done this now, and realised that my FTP login details are taking me straight to the images folder.  As such I don't need to specify a path to the image, just the image name and the deletion works.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Prikryl for the suggestion.  The issue was caused by my FTP logon details root directory being my image folder that I wanted to delete.  As such, specifying a path when already in the correct folder was resulting in me being unable to find the file.  All I needed to do was provide the image name and it worked.